# Менять цвет svg иконки при наведении

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно чтобы при наведении на иконку менялся цвет с серого на градиент синего (есть исходники обеих вариантов).

На скрине видно что мне требуется. Так же иконки должны быть с плавной анимацией и быть кликабельными (переводить на другой сайт). Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иконки встроены в разметку или указаны в стилях?

Comment: встроены в разметку

Answer (score 3):

```css
.icon-link svg {
  transition: fill 0.3s linear;
}
.icon-link:hover svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<a href='#' class='icon-link'>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <path d="M512,97.248c-19.04,8.352-39.328,13.888-60.48,16.576c21.76-12.992,38.368-33.408,46.176-58.016
            c-20.288,12.096-42.688,20.64-66.56,25.408C411.872,60.704,384.416,48,354.464,48c-58.112,0-104.896,47.168-104.896,104.992
            c0,8.32,0.704,16.32,2.432,23.936c-87.264-4.256-164.48-46.08-216.352-109.792c-9.056,15.712-14.368,33.696-14.368,53.056
            c0,36.352,18.72,68.576,46.624,87.232c-16.864-0.32-33.408-5.216-47.424-12.928c0,0.32,0,0.736,0,1.152
            c0,51.008,36.384,93.376,84.096,103.136c-8.544,2.336-17.856,3.456-27.52,3.456c-6.72,0-13.504-0.384-19.872-1.792
            c13.6,41.568,52.192,72.128,98.08,73.12c-35.712,27.936-81.056,44.768-130.144,44.768c-8.608,0-16.864-0.384-25.12-1.44
            C46.496,446.88,101.6,464,161.024,464c193.152,0,298.752-160,298.752-298.688c0-4.64-0.16-9.12-0.384-13.568
            C480.224,136.96,497.728,118.496,512,97.248z"/>
    </svg>
</a>
```

В примере стилей используется свойство `fill`. В зависимости от иконки так же может использоваться свойство `stroke`.

Comment: Честно признаться не понимаю как вы это сделали? Куда вставлять ссылку на мою иконку? Как выбрать цвет градиента?

Comment: По ссылке изменение стилей работать не будет. Содержимое SVG должно быть встроено в саму разметку

Comment: @EssleJaxcate можно через маски сделать изменение цвета однотонного свг элемента, но это не кроссбраузерно и узко.

Answer (score 0):

Или HTML:

```
    <i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>
```

CSS:

```
    .fa-spinner {
      color: red;
    }
    .fa-spinner:hover {
      color: green;
    }
```